# exposing c++ custom type to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have following C++ custom object, which is wished to be used in QML as `enum` type:

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "database/uepeoplemodel.h"
#include "core/uestatus.h"
#include "core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    UeStatus* ueApplicationStatus=new UeStatus(qApp);
    UePeopleModel* uePeopleModel=new UePeopleModel(qApp);

    QObject::connect(uePeopleModel,
                     SIGNAL(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)),
                     ueApplicationStatus,
                     SLOT(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)));

    uePeopleModel->ueConnectToDatabase();

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uePeopleModel",
                                             uePeopleModel);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueApplicationStatus",
                                             ueApplicationStatus);
    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("uePeopleModel"),
                            uePeopleModel);

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus>("si.mikroelektronika",
                                                                                           1,
                                                                                           0,
                                                                                           "UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus",
                                                                                           "Database Connection Status");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

I get following compile errors (using `gcc version 4.9.2` on `Linux work002 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`:

> In file included from
>   /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:40:0,
>                    from /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qabstractanimation.h:37,
>                    from /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/QtCore:4,
>                    from /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/QtQmlDepends:3,
>                    from /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/QtQml:3,
>                    from ../ueBlagajnaClient/main.cpp:1: /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:88:5:
>   error: class definition may not be declared a friend
>        friend Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR const QMetaObject *qt_getEnumMetaObject(ENUM) Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT { return &staticMetaObject; } \
>        ^ ../ueBlagajnaClient/database/../core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h:17:5:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'Q_ENUM'
>        Q_ENUM(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)
>        ^ /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:88:35:
>   error: 'QMetaObject' is neither function nor member function; cannot
>   be declared friend
>        friend Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR const QMetaObject *qt_getEnumMetaObject(ENUM) Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT { return &staticMetaObject; } \
>                                      ^ ../ueBlagajnaClient/database/../core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h:17:5:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'Q_ENUM'
>        Q_ENUM(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)
>        ^ /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:88:35:
>   error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
>        friend Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR const QMetaObject *qt_getEnumMetaObject(ENUM) Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT { return &staticMetaObject; } \
>                                      ^ ../ueBlagajnaClient/database/../core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h:17:5:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'Q_ENUM'
>        Q_ENUM(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)
>        ^ /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:88:73:
>   error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'qt_getEnumMetaObject' with no
>   type [-fpermissive]
>        friend Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR const QMetaObject *qt_getEnumMetaObject(ENUM) Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT { return &staticMetaObject; } \
>                                                                            ^
>   ../ueBlagajnaClient/database/../core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h:17:5:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'Q_ENUM'
>        Q_ENUM(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)
>        ^ ../ueBlagajnaClient/database/../core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h: In
>   member function 'int*
>   UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::qt_getEnumMetaObject(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)':
>   /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:88:101:
>   error: cannot convert 'const QMetaObject*' to 'int*' in return
>        friend Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR const QMetaObject *qt_getEnumMetaObject(ENUM) Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT { return &staticMetaObject; } \
>                                                                                                        ^
>   ../ueBlagajnaClient/database/../core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h:17:5:
>   note: in expansion of macro 'Q_ENUM'
>        Q_ENUM(UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)
>        ^ In file included from /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/QtQml:9:0,
>                    from ../ueBlagajnaClient/main.cpp:1: /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/qqml.h: In instantiation
>   of 'int qmlRegisterUncreatableType(const char*, int, int, const char*,
>   const QString&) [with T =
>   UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus]':
>   ../ueBlagajnaClient/main.cpp:35:120:   required from here
>   /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/qqml.h:83:59: error:
>   'staticMetaObject' is not a member of
>   'UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus'
>        const char *className = T::staticMetaObject.className(); \
>                                                              ^ /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/qqml.h:134:5: note: in
>   expansion of macro 'QML_GETTYPENAMES'
>        QML_GETTYPENAMES
>        ^ In file included from /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/QtQml:9:0,
>                    from ../ueBlagajnaClient/main.cpp:1: /opt/QtOpenSource55/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtQml/qqml.h:144:51: error:
>   'staticMetaObject' is not a member of
>   'UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus'
>            uri, versionMajor, versionMinor, qmlName, &T::staticMetaObject,
>                                                      ^ Makefile:1319: recipe for target 'main.o' failed make: *** [main.o] Error 1 08:04:15:
>   The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2. Error while
>   building/deploying project ueBlagajnaClient (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.0 GCC
>   64bit) When executing step "Make"

Why and how do I get rid of this error? How am I misusing method `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`?

Comment: Is declaration of UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus visible for the place where you call qmlRegisterType ?

Comment: @N1ghtLight yes it is, the header file is included in `main.cpp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `qmlRegisterType`, the class used must be a class that inherits `QObject` and has the `Q_OBJECT` macro:

```
class UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum StatusEnum
    {
        NOT_CONNECTED=false,
        CONNECTED=true
    }
    Q_ENUM(StatusEnum)
    ...
}
```

In QML, you can create an instance of it, just like you do with any other QML-class.

EDIT:
However, since all you want to do is use the enum-values, use `qmlRegisterUncreatableType` instead. This way the type gets registered, but you can't create an instance of it.

To access the enum values, import the type and use it like any other enum:

```
connectionProperty: UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus.CONNECTED;
```

Comment: Or [Q_GADGET](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#value-types) for value types.

Comment: @Felix do I need to work with `StatusEnum` or `UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus` while parametrizing signal/slot or registering the type?

Comment: @Marko In this case, you have to use `UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus::StatusEnum`, since that's the real enum

Comment: @Felix just one more thing, where do I define `connectionProperty` from your previous post, as normal `property`?

Comment: And how do I pass connection status to QML signal as parameter?

Comment: Yes, it's a normal property. You pass the enum just as any other, default Qt-Enum. Check this post for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329401/exposing-an-enum-in-a-qml-signal